# You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-framework-version

Visual Studio 2022

I recently created an automation framework "prototype" project for my work. I created a nuget package for this framework following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework) instructions. I then created a new, separate project to try and install this nuget package with and I'm getting the following error:
[image]

I've looked through a lot of posts about this error and checked multiple things but nothing seems to be working. I've double checked that both my framework project and the target project are both the same output type / target framework:

**Framework project:**

[image]

---

**Target project:**

[image]

I've also checked both the **csproj** files for these projects and they both reference **v4.7.2** as well.
[image]

I feel like I should be able to install this nuget package based on all this and the posts I've been reading that have fixes.

**UPDATE**
Nuspec file for the framework project
[image]

Comment: What's the nuspec file look like (or, if you don't have one, what's the folder structure of the nupgk file)? Are your dlls files in a folder called "net472"?

Comment: @gunr2171 i updated to include a ss of the framework nuspec file.

i also went through the folders in the framework directory and i dont see anything with net472. it looks like the dll files are directly in the bin/debug and bin/release folders.

Comment: I checked out your package (you don't have to publish it to nuget.org to use it, you can publish to a local folder while developing/testing) and it just contains your uncompiled project. You must have done something wrong with `nuget pack`.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren interesting, thanks. ill go back through the steps again and try to do it again

Comment: Do you mind adding the text files from your screenshots as text rather than images? Can't copy+paste or search pngs. Your nuspec file doesn't include any files. I'd expect to see a <group> or <files> elements.

Answer (score 0):

Karl's comment above seemed to do the trick. Somewhere I seemed to have missed a `nuget pack`. Once I did that it looks like the nuget package is able to be installed successfully.